# Turning an array into an array of objects with Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array:

```
var countries = ['Austria', 'America', 'Australia'];
```

I know you can turn that into an object with Underscore.js like this:

```
_.object(['name', 'name2', 'name3'], countries));
```

How can I turn the array into an array of objects that looks like this?

```
  var countriesObject = [
    { name: 'Austria' },
    { name: 'America' },
    { name: 'Australia' }
  ];
```

(with all the keys named `name`).

Answer (score 3):

No need to use Underscore.js for that. You can do it with plain javascript:

```
var new_arr = [];

countries.forEach(function(country) {
  var new_obj = {};
  new_obj.name = country;
  new_arr.push(new_obj);
});

console.table(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var countriesObject = _.map (countries,function (country){
    return {
            name: country
     }
 }
```

Comment: missing a `)` at the end.