# Turning an array into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I turn this array with keys

```
> dd
[ 'DeviceName',
  'counter1',
  'counter2',
  'counter3',
  'counter4' ]
```

into this object array with objects

```
[
    { data: 'DeviceName' },
    { data: 'counter1' },
    { data: 'counter2' },
    { data: 'counter3' },
    { data: 'counter4' }
]
```

I have tried this function, but the problem is that the data key is the same in them all.

Is there a way around this?

```
 newdd=function toObject(arr) {
      var rv = {};
      var a =[];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        rv["data"] = arr[i];
        a.push(rv);
        }
      return a;
    }
```

This gives me:

```
> newdd(dd)
[ { data: 'counter4' },
  { data: 'counter4' },
  { data: 'counter4' },
  { data: 'counter4' },
  { data: 'counter4' } ]
```

Comment: think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280580/turning-an-array-into-an-array-of-objects-with-underscore-js) might be what I want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
dd.map(function(element)
{
    return { data: element };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because objects in JavaScript are [passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) (or really [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)), not by value, so you're always referencing the same object.

Just move your assignment for `rv = {}` inside your `for` loop and it should fix your problem. Reassigning `rv` to a new object as opposed to modifying the existing instance will result in the desired behavior.

```
newdd = function toObject(arr) {
    var a =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        var rv = {};
        rv["data"] = arr[i];
        a.push(rv);
    }

    return a;
 }
```

See [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) on the Mozilla Developer Network to help build your understanding of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
function toObject(arr) {
    var a =[];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        a.push({ data: arr[i] });
    }
    return a;
}
```